# How to do sort(as alphabetical odder) within a for loop as expected below in xslt or xsl-fo?

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

I want to create a table  Which contain two columns as product type and number of quantity in XSL-Fo. 
In the XML input file Type node contain 00 then in the table the product should be come like "Other"

```
if Type element value is 
    00 then "Other" like wise
    51 = Business Loan – General
    05 = Personal Loan
```

I want to see all product in alphabetical ascending odder.

This is my Input XML

```
     <product>
                     <months>
                          <Type>00</Type>
                          <Number>2</Number>
                    </months>
                    <months>
                          <Type>51</Type>
                           <Number>2</Number>
                     </months>
                     <months>
                           <Type>05</Type>
                           <Number>1</Number>
                      </months>                    
            </product>
```

I tried this Here

```
     quantity
     <fo:table>
          <fo:table-body> 
             <fo:table-row>
                 <fo:table-cell>
                      <fo:block >Product Type</fo:block>
                 </fo:table-cell>
                 <fo:table-cell>
                      <fo:block>Quantity</fo:block>
                 </fo:table-cell>

     <xsl:for-each select=" Product/months">
     <xsl:variable name="Variable" select="Type"></xsl:variable>
      <fo:table-row>
             <fo:table-cell>
             <fo:block >      
                <xsl:choose>
                     <xsl:when test="Type[contains(text(),'05')]">
                        Personal Loan
                     </xsl:when>    
                     <xsl:when test="ProductType[contains(text(),'55')]">
                     Business Loan – General 
                     </xsl:when>
                     <xsl:when test="ProductType[contains(text(),'00')]">
                     Other
                     </xsl:when>
               </xsl:choose>
           </fo:block>
         </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell>
          <fo:block>
            <xsl:value-of select="Number"/>
          </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
       </xsl:for-each>
     </fo:table-body>
    </fo:table>
```

I got the O/p like below

```
                     Product Type            |            Quantity
   -----------------------------------------------------------
   Other                   |                2
   Business Loan – General |                2      
   Personal Loan           |                1

   but Actual Expected OUT/PUT is this

   Product Type            |            Quantity
   -----------------------------------------------------------
   Business Loan – General |                2
   Other                   |                2
   Personal Loan           |                1
```

Comment: Do you have an actual question?

Comment: Actually I am unable to sort.

Comment: I used a foreach loop within that I replaced all all values 05= personal like wise ,After that I want to sort But I don't know how to do please help me. When I am using sorting It's sorting like 00,05,51 not as expected.I want to apply sort on the replaced values. which give the result 51,00,05

Comment: Please edit your question and add your XSLT code - see: [mcve].

Comment: I added my code please check it and suggest me

Comment: Can you say which version of XSLT you can use? Can you use XSLT 2.0 or XSLT 3.0?

Comment: Yes I can use XSLT 2.0, Currently I am using XSLT 1.0

Answer (score 0):

If can use XSLT 2.0, you can create a variable to hold elements that represent your mappings

```
<xsl:variable name="products">
  <map-entry key="05">Personal Loan</map-entry>
  <map-entry key="51">Business Loan – General</map-entry>
  <map-entry key="00">Other</map-entry>
</xsl:variable>
```

Then you can use a key to look these up by the `key` attribute

```
 <xsl:key name="map" match="map-entry" use="@key" />
```

You would then use this key in a sort, like so:

```
<xsl:for-each select="product/months">
  <xsl:sort select="key('map', Type, $products)" />
```

(As an aside, do make sure you use the correct case, as in your XSLT you were using `Product`, not `product`)

Try this XSLT, which you can see in action at http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPzifoQ

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:variable name="products">
    <map-entry key="05">Personal Loan</map-entry>
    <map-entry key="51">Business Loan – General</map-entry>
    <map-entry key="00">Other</map-entry>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:key name="map" match="map-entry" use="@key" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <fo:table>
      <fo:table-body> 
        <fo:table-row>
          <fo:table-cell>
            <fo:block>Product Type</fo:block>
          </fo:table-cell>
          <fo:table-cell>
            <fo:block>Quantity</fo:block>
          </fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-row>
        <xsl:for-each select="product/months">
          <xsl:sort select="key('map', Type, $products)" />
          <fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-cell>
              <fo:block>
                <xsl:value-of select="key('map', Type, $products)" />
              </fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
            <fo:table-cell>
              <fo:block>
                <xsl:value-of select="Number"/>
              </fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
          </fo:table-row>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </fo:table-body>
    </fo:table> 
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note, if you can use XSLT 3.0, there is a dedicated "map" function you can use, which slightly simplifies things

Try this XSLT 3.0, which you can see in action at http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bnnZVx

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:variable name="products" as="map(xs:string, xs:string)">
    <xsl:map>
      <xsl:map-entry key="'05'" select="'Personal Loan'"/>
      <xsl:map-entry key="'51'" select="'Business Loan – General'"/>
      <xsl:map-entry key="'00'" select="'Other'"/>
    </xsl:map>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <fo:table>
      <fo:table-body> 
        <fo:table-row>
          <fo:table-cell>
            <fo:block>Product Type</fo:block>
          </fo:table-cell>
          <fo:table-cell>
            <fo:block>Quantity</fo:block>
          </fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-row>
        <xsl:for-each select="product/months">
          <xsl:sort select="$products(Type)" />
          <fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-cell>
              <fo:block>
                <xsl:value-of select="$products(Type)" />
              </fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
            <fo:table-cell>
              <fo:block>
                <xsl:value-of select="Number"/>
              </fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
          </fo:table-row>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </fo:table-body>
    </fo:table> 
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you could look at this. For example, you could avoid sorting altogether - esp. if you only have 3 possible product types - by applying templates to each type in turn.

Here's a simplified example:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/product">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Product Type</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="months[Type='51']"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="months[Type='00']"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="months[Type='05']"/>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="months">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="Type='51'">Business Loan – General</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="Type='05'">Personal Loan</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="Type='00'">Other</xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="Number"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Another option is to sort by custom order - again, using the codes in their intended order:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/product">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Product Type</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:variable name="sort-order">|51|00|05|</xsl:variable>
        <xsl:for-each select="months">
            <xsl:sort select="string-length(substring-before($sort-order, concat('|', Type, '|')))" data-type="number"/>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="Type='51'">Business Loan – General</xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="Type='05'">Personal Loan</xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="Type='00'">Other</xsl:when>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Number"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```