# XML Sort Using custom order

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt

I need to sort an XML base of a custom order. Easy to do it by alphabetic order, but I have not found any guidance so far on how to do it.

I’m using **XSLT1.0** with a **Text** output

So I need to sort in this order *snake|cat|dog*

My XML look like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<root>
    <properties>
<categorie>dog</categorie>
<data>...</data>
     </properties>
     <properties>
<categorie>cat</categorie>
<data>...</data>
     </properties>
     <properties>
<categorie>cat</categorie>
<data>...</data>
     </properties>
     <properties>
<categorie>snake</categorie>
<data>...</data>
    </properties>
    <properties>
<categorie>snake</categorie>
<data>...</data>
     </properties>
</root>
```

my XSLT like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/*">
<xsl:for-each select="/root/properties">
<xsl:sort select="categorie"/>
<xsl:value-of select="categorie"/>

</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any guidances appreciated... ;)

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54092492/3016153

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way. I know it's not pretty but if you don't have too many categories it does the trick...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <!-- Snake -->
        <xsl:for-each select="/root/properties[categorie='snake']">
            <xsl:value-of select="categorie"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <!-- Cat -->
        <xsl:for-each select="/root/properties[categorie='cat']">
            <xsl:value-of select="categorie"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <!-- Dog -->
        <xsl:for-each select="/root/properties[categorie='dog']">
            <xsl:value-of select="categorie"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3MEdvh9

Comment: Thanks Sebastien!
With this approach, I fear I will have to duplicate a bunch of others XSLT command that need to go after the sorting.

Comment: I have found my answer in this post:

http://www.robdinardo.com/content/how-sort-xsl-output-order-custom-string-list-or-arbitrary-strings